# twiiter max_id and since_id

Tags: php, api, twitter

i am using twitter user_timeline api to get all tweets of a user .

it returns 200 in single request but problem is that i want to get all tweets if tweets are like 400 or 500

below is my code that give 200 tweets in output :

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$url1="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$sc_name = 'DailyRapPics';
$count ='700';

$getfield = '?screen_name='.$sc_name.'&exclude_replies=true&include_rts=true&contributor_details=false';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$tweets  = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url1, $requestMethod)->performRequest();

$tweetarray = json_decode($tweets);
$l = 0;
foreach($tweetarray as $mytweets){
$l++;
}
echo 'total values->>>>>>>>>'.$l;
```

when i see twitter there are field like since_id,max_id

how can i use it to get all tweet of user less than 3200 of twitter limit please help me

what could be value od max_id and since_id here please guide

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might not be directly related but just for your help, You need to use max_id and since_id as "strings" or floats. You will save yourself a lot of headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question regards to how to paginate (since the request param "count" has a maximum of 200 results per query according to [Twitter's user_timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)), but it allows you to get the last 3200 tweets.

The right way to paginate it is with the ids of the tweets in an algorithm like this:

1. Initialise variables

   ```
   $all_tweets = array();
   $max_tweets_per_response = 200;
   $last_tweet_id = 0;
   $max_tweets_you_want_to_obtain = 666;
   ```
2. **$tweets** = result of the query the same way you are doing it but also adding the params:
   count=**$max_tweets_per_response** & since_id=**$last_tweet_id**
3. Decode response received from Twitter and merge it with the variable that will contain all 3200 results.

   ```
   $tweetarray = json_decode($tweets);
   $all_tweets = array_merge($all_tweets, $tweetarray);
   ```
4. **$last_tweet_id** = the ID of the LAST tweet you received, that right now will be the one in the variable **$tweet**
5. Iterate from *step 2* onwards until

   ```
   count($tweetarray) < $max_tweets_per_response
   or
   count($all_tweets) >= $max_tweets_you_want_to_obtain
   ```
6. Do whatever you need with all your tweets, that will now be contained in variable **$all_tweets**

   ```
   echo 'total values->>>>>>>>>'.count($all_tweets);
   ```